# Equivalent formula for the sum of first $n$ values of the number of divisors function

Tags: number-theory, integers, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, divisor-counting-function

In the notes of the following OEIS sequence( https://oeis.org/A006218), it is stated that
$$\sigma_0(1)  + \sigma_0(2)  +... + \sigma_0(n)  =  \left[ \dfrac{n}{1} \right] +   \left[ \dfrac{n}{2} \right] +... +   \left[ \dfrac{n}{n}  \right] , $$
where $\sigma_0(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$, and $[x] $ denotes the integer part of $x$.
How can one prove this identity? I tried approaching it inductively but i failed.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{d|k} d = \sum_{d=1}^n\sum_{k=1,d|k}^{n}d = \sum_{d=1}^n d\left\lfloor \frac {n} {d}\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma(k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{d\mid j}1=\sum_{d=1}^n
\sum_{j:1\le j\le n,d\mid j}=\sum_{j=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac nj\right\rfloor.$$
In words, $\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma(k)$ counts the number of pairs $(j,k)$
of positive integers with $j\mid k$ and $k\le n$. In each such pair
$1\le j\le n$, and the number of admissible $(j,k)$ for a given $j$
is the number of multiples of $j$ up to $n$, which is
$\left\lfloor n/j\right\rfloor$.

Comment: This trick of switching the order of summation is very common and worth remembering; it can be used to prove lots of interesting identities.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you were to calculate the left-hand side by hand, how many times in total would $1$ be counted as a divisor of one of the numbers from $1$ to $n$? How many times would $2$ be counted as a divisor? What about $3$?